# Derive Perpetual Bond Price

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

It is known that a perpetual bond with coupon $c$ has price
$$P=\frac{c}{r}$$
How do you get to this price? Is $r$ stated in discrete or continuous compounding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Consol Bond is a bond that pays an annual coupon of c every year. Therefore its price is $P=\frac{c}{1+r}+\frac{c}{(1+r)^2}+\cdots$.  Factoring out the c and using the known formula for a geometric series, namely $u+u^2+u^3+\cdots = \frac{u}{1-u}$ we get $P=c[\frac{1}{1+r}/(1-\frac{1}{1+r})]=\frac{c}{r}$

Clearly this is a discrete compounding, not continous compounding formula.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the price in continuous compounding?

Comment: Assuming one coupon payment per year, by a very similar reasoning it is $P=c\frac{e^{-r}}{1-e^{-r}}$

Comment: In this [link](https://www.bionicturtle.com/forum/threads/in-converting-continuous-rate-to-discrete-does-it-matter-how-often-interest-is-paid.6974/) it finds that $r_c=\ln r-1$. But this would contradict your formula for $P$ in continuous compounding?

Comment: The correct relationship is $r_c=\ln (1+r)$  (see for example post of May 1, 2013 in your link, with n=1)

Comment: Thanks, then we get $r=e^{r_c}-1\Rightarrow P=\frac{c}{r}=\frac{c}{e^{r_c}-1}$. This is the same result as in your formula above when extending by $\frac{e^r}{e^r}$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition; to get your required annual perpetual return of **r**, you trivially pay **1 USD** up-front to get **r USD** annually. To get those annual payments from the consol bond in question you need to have **r/c** bonds (each paying **c USD** annually). To get those bonds for your **1 USD** up-front payment, they have to sell at the price of **c/r USD** which is hereby demonstrated.

Comment: Very nice intuitive proof.