# How is the present value of tax shield of constant and perpetual debt derived?

Tags: present-value, debt, tax

According to [this site](https://www.intechopen.com/books/financial-management-from-an-emerging-market-perspective/review-of-tax-shield-valuation-and-its-application-to-emerging-markets-finance), the present value of tax shield of constant and perpetual debt is:

corporate tax rate × interest payment ÷ expectd return on debt

I understand the part about  "corporate tax rate × interest payment". But why is expectd return on debt be divided here? (I think that it is also not from summing geometric sequence.)

Comment: In general you find the value of a perpetuity by dividing the annual payment by the interest rate: $PV=\frac{C}{i}$ (so called Consol Formula). Here for $i$ they are using "expected return on debt".

Comment: Thank you. I find answer here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22294/derive-perpetual-bond-price

Answer (score 0):

Interest payment is determined by the bond (either fixed or variable), expected return varies according to market movements. It is effectively the discount factor.